# nonzero digits in decimal representation of $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, decimal-expansion

let $1,d_1d_2d_3\dots$ be a decimal representation of $\sqrt{2}$.

Prove that at least one $d_i$ with $10^{1999}<i<10^{2000}$ is nonzero.

I have no idea how to solve it.
I think that the given bounds mean the year only, and one can generalize it replacing $1999$ and $2000$ by $n$ and $n+1$ respectively.

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that there is no "good" rational approximation to $\sqrt{2}$, more precisely that $|p^2-2q^2|\ge 1$ unless $p$and $q$ are both $0$.

Comment: @tong_nor or anybody else, do you know where this problem could come from?

Comment: from russian or ukrainian book or math forum (similarily as in case many other questions I posted here, and as usual I don't remember the source, because I read lots of things, I take  problems that seem interesting to me, I try to solve them myself and after quite a long time without crucial idea the problem is being posted here).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing to remember to get a grasp on the problem is that the proposed number of consecutive zeroes is *nine times* the number of digits to that point.

So, assuming that the digits in the stated portion of the decimal expansion are all zero:

Separate $\sqrt 2$ into two parts, $A$ and $B$, where $A$ consists of all the digits with place value greater than $ 10^{-10^{1999}} $ and $B$ is the (irrational) portion less than $10^{-10^{2000}}$. Now $(\sqrt 2)^2 = (A+B)^2 = A^2 + 2AB + B^2$. Now the smallest (non-zero) digit of $A$ has a squared value of no less than $10^{-2*10^{1999}}$ and the largest place value that can be affected by the result of $2AB$ is approximately $2.8\cdot10^{-10^{2000}}$. Therefore these calculations do not interact and we are left with non-zero digits in the result, which **contradicts** the definition of $\sqrt 2$.

Therefore there must be non-zero digits within that portion of the decimal representation of $\sqrt 2$.

The side observation is that we can't have more consecutive zeros than we have had digits so far in the representation.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need any fancy theorems. You just need to think about what happens when you square such a number, digit by digit. All those zeroes (followed, sooner or later, by a non-zero digit) will result in a block of zeroes in the product, followed by a non-zero digit. Which is impossible, because the square is $2.0000\ldots$

**Edited to add:** I have left out the details, but Joffan's answer does an excellent job of filling them in.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that all those digits are zero, we have that $$m=10^{10^{1999}}\sqrt{2}$$
is almost an integer, but that cannot happen in virtue of [Hurwitz' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28number_theory%29). In particular, for any convergent $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{2}=[1;2,2,2,\ldots]$ we have:
$$\left|\sqrt{2}-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|\geq \frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|=\frac{1}{2q_n q_{n+1}}\approx\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{2}+1)\,q_n^2}. $$

Comment: I don't really understand how Hurwitz' theorem proves that $$m=10^{10^{1999}}·\sqrt 2$$ can't almost be an integer...

Comment: .................?